# How to delete the duplicate records from the whole database

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

**Today I have tried to fire the job that checks for the redundancy in the particular table.**

I have one table `EmpDetails`

`Please find the screenshot to find the records in the table`

[image]

A job runs from the sql in every 2 min and delete the redundancy from the table.

`Result of the job:` :

[image: <code>Result of the job:</code>]

`But my expectations from the job are some bit higher, I want from the job to check the the redudancy from the whole database not from the single table.`

Can anyone please suggest me, is that really possible or not. If it is possible so what should be the right approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should first define what a duplicate is. The same primary-key, the same value in any column, the same in at least two columns, etc pp., any exceptions?

Comment: when you click on the first screenshot, you can see the id(1) is repeated two times at the last and in the second image my job delete the duplicate id.

Comment: The solution isn't to make a better job for deleting duplicates - it's to apply appropriate constraints in the database so that duplicates aren't possible in the first place.

Comment: Yes, you are right but sometimes there are some situations where we keep checking our database for any type of redundancy. I want to create that kind of job.

Answer (score 0):

You should first define what a duplicate is. And for running across multiple DB use can either loop through the databases or you can use EXEC sp_MSforeachdb  which is an undocumented  sp

Thanks